# Inconsistent behaviour concatenating macro variables

Tags: string, sas, sas-macro

I am trying to create a string by concatenating several variables/delimiters within a macro:

```
%macro write_to_string();
%let delim = = ;
%let string = %sysfunc(catx(%str( ), 
                             &string, \,
                             step start,
                             %nrstr(%superq(delim)),
                             &etls_stepStartTime,
                             |,
                             output table,
                             %nrstr(%superq(delim)),
                             &SYSLAST, 
                             |,
                             transform return code,
                             %nrstr(%superq(delim)),
                             &trans_rc));
%mend;
```

The macro is called at the end of several transformations (within SAS DI), so the string keeps having text appended at the end.

If the each instance of `%nrstr(%superq(delim))` is replaced with some other delimiter, `:` say, then the above macro behaves as intended. But with the code as above what I get a `0` followed by the last string to have been appended.

I am quite ignorant about macro variables and functions and am struggling to understand

- Why the choice of delimiter seems to affect whether the string is properly appended
- Why macro variables sometimes need to be referenced with the preceding `&` and sometimes not.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

The input variables in the code above are autogenerated by the SAS DI system and reset after each transformation in the job. The values look something like

`&etls_stepStartTime = 16FEB2017:17:25:37`

`&SYSLAST = WORK.MY_TABLE_NAME`

`&trans_rc = 0`

Here the value of `&trans_rc` will indicate the error/warning status of the last transformation that ran.

So my desired output (with the `&delim` variable working) would be values of the form

`step start = 16FEB2017:17:25:37 | output table = WORK.MY_TABLE_NAME | transform return code = 0`

delimited by `\`. As mentioned above, what I get is only the last value (the one corresponding to the last transformation) with a preceding `0\`, unless I change the delimiter to some non-reserved character constant.

Comment: Can you post input values for all of the macro variables referenced by this code along with the results you are getting and the results you want.

Comment: Hey @Tom. The macro variables here are auto-generated by the SAS DI system, and change depending on when in the program they are called (the system sets the values after each transformation). I will post an example.

Comment: Does the DELIM value change? Or did you make it a macro variable because you were trying to get it to work?  Since you only use three times might just be easier to not have the macro variable and just put the `=` where you want them in your resulting macro variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use %SYSFUNC() with the CAT... series of functions. First of all you don't need them as in macro code you can just place the text where you want it.  Second since those functions can work on either numeric or character arguments. This means that SAS has to try to figure out whether the text that your macro code is generating as the arguments represent a number or a character string.  That is probably why the equal signs result in zeros. SAS is treating the equal sign as equality test so the zero means that the values on each side are not equal.

```
%let string =&string \ step start &delim &etls_stepStartTime ;
%let string =&string | output table &delim &SYSLAST ;
%let string =&string | transform return code &delim &trans_rc ;
```

Comment: Hey @Tom. I'm really grateful for this answer. Not only did it solve my problem, but it solved other issues I was facing. Macros are endlessly confusing to me and I never know why something works or not. Thanks!